# Rearranging letters from a list

Tags: python

This may be a bit confusing to read but what I would like to do is take any string and rearrange the letters based on an input from the user of the program. So for example, line = "Romeo and Juliet", key=3. The encoded line would start with line[0] R, then move 3 characters down to E, then A, then a SPACE. Then once i reach the end of the list it would circle back and start with line[1], add 3, and so on until all the characters have been used. So the end result would be "Rea ltoonJim due". I'm assuming this will use a loop and that's the part I'm stuck on. This is my current code:

```
key = int(input("Enter the key: "))
sent = input("Enter a sentence: ")
print()# for turnin
print()

print("With a key of:",key)
print("Original sentence:",sent)
print()

split = list(sent)

for i in range(len(split)):
    print(split[0+i*key])
```

So I have the list set up, and this gives me the first few letters that I need but I get an error:
`IndexError: list index out of range.`

So once it reaches the final character, how would i get it to loop back to `split[1]` and continue through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String slicing can take a "skip" factor, so:

```
>>> s = 'Romeo and Juliet'
>>> s[0::3] # every 3rd letter starting from 0
'Rea lt'
>>> s[1::3] # every 3rd letter starting from 1
'oonJi'
```

Put that in a loop and join them together:

```
>>> ''.join(s[i::3] for i in range(3))
'Rea ltoonJim due'
```

As a general function:

```
>>> def rearrange(s,skip):
...     return ''.join(s[i::skip] for i in range(skip))
... 
>>> rearrange(s,3)
'Rea ltoonJim due'
>>> rearrange(s,5)
'R Jtoaumnledio e'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do `split[(i*key) % len(split)]` to rotate around the list. Look up more on [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).